# Any software that can sync one local folder to multiple FTP folders?

Tags: backup, ftp, sync

I've searched high and low, and while there are lots of nice software like goodsync, syncbackpro, and more, everything I could find syncs one to one only.

I need to sync one folder (local windows or from an FTP source) to many FTP folders - basically my websites.

Right now I had to resort to syncbackpro which is great but i need to create multiple profiles for each website and run sync on each profile one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mentioned tools like goodsync and syncbackpro With the others, you have to create multiple jobs for each FTP and then run each manually, so maybe you would try Gs Richcopy360, you can just create multiple jobs (a job for each FTP ), but then link the first job to the second, then to third and fourth....etc.  Which the first job completes, the second job gets started automatically then the third and fourth.   You can only start the first job and the rest will follow by themselves. you will use a feature called "Start job in the post operation", if this strategy is suitable for you, please check this pic
[image]